# Entity reference in a content type for a taxonomy. Limit it to a single value

Tags: 8

I have a content type. Lets' call it `Events`. For said content type I have a field(`event_type`) set as an entity reference to a taxonomy named `Event Type`.

I've set the limit on the field(`event_type`) to a single value.

However, visually, I can add more than one value as a comma separated list of values.

[image]

[image]

As far as I can tell the last taxonomy term is kept as the value.

**This raises the problem that at some point in time somebody may very well add more than one thinking that all of them will be kept.**

---

Is there a way I can visually limit the values entered? Perhaps a dropdown or radio buttons or something?

If anybody can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

---

Also, I've searched in the [Drupal 8 know bug list](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal), but quite frankly the list is huge and I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the widget to a "Select list" instead of "Autocomplete (Tags style)".

You can find this on the "Manage form display" tab of the content type.